# Как импортировать ttk из tkinter Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Пытаюсь скомпилировать в exe файл, но получаю ошибку (картинка).
Импорчу в коде так, иначе будет ошибка, что файла ttk нет. На компе библиотека лежит по такому пути: C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\tkinter

(Если запускать просто python файл, то всё работает)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, scrolledtext, messagebox
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие танцы с бубном, конечно... Вот вопросы, которые помогли решить проблему с ttk
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380748/how-to-make-pyinstaller-import-the-ttk-theme
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369108/cannot-convert-python-script-into-an-executable-using-pyinstaller-empty-dist-fo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035724/python-error-no-module-named-pkg-resources

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю, с помощью чего вы собираете .exe, поэтому посоветую Pyinstaller, меня он никогда не подводил, все зависимости всегда подтягивает.

```
pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller вашскрипт.py
```

Comment: Так через него и делал)